# Unable to show an Interstitial ad on iOS Simulator in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have replaced my test ad Unit ID with my Goggle Ad Mob interstitial Ad Unit ID in he View Controller. But, Now I can't see my ad on the iOS Simulator on Xcode. Earlier it was showing me the add with the test mode. Could anyone please let me know the reason for such an issue? Thanks for the help!

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()        

}

func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
  var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub- ")
  interstitial.delegate = self
  interstitial.load(GADRequest())
  return interstitial
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
  interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}


@IBAction func exitButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if (interstitial.isReady) {
        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors when trying to load the interstitial? Do you have a proxy program like Charles Proxy to help debug the ad request?

Comment: @SylvanDAsh The ad appeared once and after that I am not able to see that ad again!

Comment: After an interstitial ad has been displayed, you can't display it again. You need to make a new request to get another interstitial ad

Comment: @SylvanDAsh I have fixed my code to make a new request could you please let me know if this is the right way to make a new request? Thanks for the help!

Comment: First of all, I hope you're using the correct `adUnitID` and not the one you've shared in the code sample above?

Comment: Second, you could try adding the `GADInterstitialDelegate` delegate functions to give you more info on where the ad could be failing. The functions can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial#implementing_interstitial_events)

Comment: @SylvanDAsh Thanks a lot for the help! I will go through the delegate methods once!